# Linq - How to Use NOT IN

Tags: sql, linq

I am having following query & i need to write it in linq. I am stuck in `NOT IN` part.

```
SELECT A.CODE,
       A.DATETIME,
       A.DATE 
FROM TABLE_IO A 
WHERE  A.DATE>= '01/06/2015' AND A.DATE<='01/06/2015'        
AND A.CODE NOT IN(
                   SELECT CODE 
                   FROM TABLE_ENTRY B 
                   WHERE A.CODE=B.CODE AND A.DATE=B.ENTRY_DATE AND METHOD='M'
                  )
```

How to write `NOT IN` part?

```
var data = ctx.TABLE_IO.Where(m=>m.Date >= '01/06/2015' && m.Date <= '01/06/2015')
                       .Select(m=>m).ToList();
```

Comment: Without knowing which linq provider you are using it is hard to say what methods are implemented.

Comment: Your date comparison is strange. You are using it like a char literal, you're also filtering a range where the start is the same as the end.

Comment: That is just a pseudo code, the dates are dynamic in real code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `!Any`:

```
DateTime dateToCompare = new DateTime(2015, 6, 1);
var data = ctx.TABLE_IO
    .Where(m => m.Date >= dateToCompare && m.Date <= dateToCompare)
    .Where(m => !ctx.TABLE_ENTRY
        .Any(te => m.Code == te.Code && m.Date == te.ENTRY_DATE && te.METHOD == "M"))
    .ToList();
```

I would prefer this, i'm fairly sure that it will be translated to a performant `NOT EXISTS` which has also no issues with null values like `NOT IN`/`Contains`.

The direct translation of `NOT IN`/`Contains` would be this:

```
var data = ctx.TABLE_IO
    .Where(m => m.Date >= dateToCompare && m.Date <= dateToCompare)
    .Where(m => !ctx.TABLE_ENTRY.Select(te => te.Code).Contains(m.Code))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: i think so, nothing special, a simple subquery. I think it's translated to a `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: i was confused about ``Any()`` that it will be translated to sql or not

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: Yes. `Any` works with all database driven LINQ providers and of course Linq-To-Objects. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738550(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: How to add Condition which is in my SQL Query `A.DATE=B.ENTRY_DATE`.

Comment: @Anup: i have edited my answer and modified the first example to include the date and method comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do something such as (pseudo queries below)

```
var exclusions = table_B.Where(b => [exclusion condition] ).Select(b => b.Id)
var data = ctx.TABLE_IO.Where(m => !exclusions.Contains(m.Id))
```